# How can I set audio source to hear audio from distance from low volume to higher depending on character distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character that walk and the character have attached Audio Source component and using a script I play steps audio.

But even if the character start position is a bit far from the player I can hear the steps at loud volume like it's close to the player. The volume value is static.

What I want to do is depending on the character distance from the player decrease or increase the volume value so it will give effect that the character is getting closer or more far.

[image: Audio Source]

Using this script to play the steps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FootSteps : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip[] clips;

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private GameObject[] Foots;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void Step()
    {
        if (clips.Length > 0)
        {
            AudioClip clip = GetRandomClip();

            if (audioSource.enabled == true)
            {
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
            }
        }
    }

    private AudioClip GetRandomClip()
    {
        return clips[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, clips.Length)];
    }
}
```

The player's camera have attached Audio Listener.

Comment: Expand the 3D sound settings at the bottom of your Audio Source component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [3D sound settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html):

In particular the Volume roll-off. I would assume that you are not moving the character that far relative to the maximum distance - so the attenuation is small. Try lowering the max distance. After that you can play with the curves.

Comment: I changed the Volume to 1 and the Spatiel Blend to 1 to be 3D.  In the 3D settings if I change the Volume Rolloff to Linear Rolloff then no matter what Max Distance is 500 or 200 the volume of the steps is the same too loud. If I change the Rolloff to Legarithmic Rolloff and then set the Max Distance to 200 the steps will be hear very quietly. What type of Rolloff volume should I select ? And how and to what should I set the curve/s ?

Comment: If both don't behave like you wish what about a `Custom` one?

Comment: At the end I found that setting the volume on the audio source to 0.2 spatial blend to 1 and in the 3d settings the volume to Linear and Min 4 Max 27 is working perfect for this situation.  Thanks.